# What are the inventory(MSI) options available in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, api, inventory, backorder, manage-stock

I'm looking to understand the inventory management features in Magento 2. Can someone explain the different inventory options available in Magento 2 and how they can be utilized? Specifically, I'd like to know about the following:

Stock management: How does Magento 2 handle stock management? Can it handle multiple warehouses or locations? Is it possible to set up low stock notifications?

Product quantities: How does Magento 2 track product quantities? Does it support tracking product quantities at the SKU level? Can it handle complex scenarios like bundling products or configurable products?

Stock status: How does Magento 2 determine the stock status of a product? Can it automatically update the stock status based on product availability?

Backorders: Does Magento 2 support backorders? If so, how are backordered items managed and fulfilled?

Reservations: Can Magento 2 reserve stock for pending orders or carts? How does it handle reservations and ensure accurate stock availability?

API integrations: Does Magento 2 provide APIs for inventory management? Are there any limitations or considerations when integrating with external systems?

Reporting and analytics: What kind of reporting and analytics capabilities does Magento 2 offer for inventory management? Can it generate reports on stock levels, sales velocity, or stock movement?

I appreciate any insights or experiences with using the inventory options in Magento 2. Feel free to share any best practices or recommendations for effective inventory management in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inventory management in Magento 2 offers several options to effectively manage stock levels, track product quantities, handle backorders, and more. Let's explore each aspect:

1. Stock management:
   Magento 2 provides robust stock management capabilities. It supports managing stock across multiple warehouses or locations, allowing you to track inventory separately for each. You can set up stock alerts and low stock notifications to stay informed about inventory levels and take timely actions.
2. Product quantities:
   Magento 2 tracks product quantities at the SKU level, enabling you to have granular control over stock. It handles complex scenarios such as bundling products and configurable products by accurately updating the quantities based on the associated components.
3. Stock status:
   The stock status of a product in Magento 2 is determined based on its available quantity. You can configure the system to automatically update the stock status as products are bought or restocked. This ensures that the product's availability is accurately reflected on the storefront.
4. Backorders:
   Magento 2 supports backorders, allowing customers to place orders for out-of-stock items. When an item is backordered, it is marked as such, and customers are notified accordingly. Merchants can manage backorders, fulfill them when stock is available, and keep customers informed about the order status.
5. Reservations:
   Magento 2 offers the ability to reserve stock for pending orders or carts. When a customer adds an item to their cart, the system reserves the stock for a specified duration, ensuring it remains available for that customer until the reservation expires or the order is placed.
6. API integrations:
   Inventory management in Magento 2 can be integrated with external systems using its comprehensive set of APIs. These APIs allow you to synchronize stock levels, update product quantities, and perform other inventory-related operations. However, when integrating with external systems, it's important to consider any specific limitations or considerations of the respective API.
7. Reporting and analytics:
   Magento 2 provides reporting and analytics capabilities for inventory management. You can generate reports that offer insights into stock levels, sales velocity, stock movement, and other key metrics. These reports help you make informed decisions about inventory planning, restocking, and identifying potential issues.

To effectively manage inventory in Magento 2, it is recommended to regularly monitor stock levels, set up automated notifications, and leverage the reporting features to analyze sales patterns and optimize stock management processes.

Remember that Magento 2's inventory options can be further enhanced by extensions and customization to meet specific business requirements.